# Python: Download video with Youtube and pytube - fix error (regex...)

Tags: python, pytube

When I try to run the code below, it gives me the response:

> "Python: Download video with Youtube and pytube - fix error (regex...)"

Tried multiple solutions, all to no avail.

**Here is my code:**

```py
link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEQ8CXFWLZU&t=475s&ab_channel=InternetMadeCoder"

yt = YouTube(link)

print(yt.title)
```

I have tried to reinstall pytube and I have tried downloading it from github but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Have updated my answer regarding virtual environment. Could you please provide the entire error you receive. By providing the entire error, you are more likely to get a resolution that works (or at least points you in the right direction).

Answer (score 0):

**I tried the following code:**

```py
from pytube import YouTube

link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEQ8CXFWLZU&t=475s&ab_channel=InternetMadeCoder"
yt = YouTube(link)
print(yt.title)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
3 PYTHON AUTOMATION PROJECTS FOR BEGINNERS
```

Perhaps try creating a new [python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) - as you may be experiencing a conflict with another package?  You can find a `tutorial` on how to create a virtual environment [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

I am also using **Python 3** (version 3.10.8) and **pytube-12.1.0**:

```
>>> sys.version
'3.10.8 (tags/v3.10.8:aaaf517, Oct 11 2022, 16:50:30) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Comment: What does creating a new environment mean? Thanks again!

Comment: A new `virtual environment` ensures that version of python is isolated from your standard version, such that it will only use the packages necessary for you current project. You can google "python virtual environment" - or go to https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv

Answer (score 0):

I ran **this** on my IDE:

```
from pytube import YouTube

video = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-43lLKaqBQ'

yt = YouTube(video)

print(yt.title)
```

**Response:**

```
The Animals - House of the Rising Sun (1964) HQ/Widescreen ♫ 58 YEARS AGO
```

Any chance that you can show us your python version? :)

Comment: yes of course! It is Python 3.10.6

Answer (score 0):

Working correctly with `pytube 12.1.0` & `Python 3.10.8`. Check version of pytube.